# Hexagonal tilemap is being distorted

Tags: tilemap, hexagonal-grid

So I made a hexagonal tilemap of ocean tiles and then picked a few tiles to be land. When I pick all adjacent tiles to the hexagon it usually works, but for tiles that are on certain columns it does not. Also, on these columns the tops and bottoms of tiles are missing.

It's hard to explain but here's a screenshot that should clear it up:

[image]

As you can see, on every other column the top and bottom of hexagons are missing, when all adjacent tiles are filled in to the centre tile it works fine for those columns without a bottom and top on hex, but when it's on the other column one of the adjacent tiles is displaced.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
    baseLayer.setCell((int)islands[currentTile].x , (int)islands[currentTile].y, landCell);

    baseLayer.setCell((int)islands[currentTile].x + 1, (int)islands[currentTile].y + 1, landCell);

    baseLayer.setCell((int)islands[currentTile].x + 1, (int)islands[currentTile].y, landCell);

    baseLayer.setCell((int)islands[currentTile].x , (int)islands[currentTile].y - 1, landCell);

    baseLayer.setCell((int)islands[currentTile].x - 1, (int)islands[currentTile].y, landCell);

    baseLayer.setCell((int)islands[currentTile].x , (int)islands[currentTile].y + 1, landCell);

    baseLayer.setCell((int)islands[currentTile].x - 1, (int)islands[currentTile].y + 1, landCell);
```

Comment: What are you using to render the hexagons?

Comment: @Kevin van der Velden HexagonalTiledMapRenderer

Comment: Does this solve your problem? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106640/why-is-libgdxs-hexagonaltiledmaprenderer-adding-extra-space

Comment: @Kevin van der Velden It may make the tops and bottoms visible but it doesnt explain why for some reason placing adjacent tiles does not work for tiles on those columns :/

Comment: You have a rounding error occurring. Check your pixel placement values carefully for both odd and even columns of hexes. I encountered the same problem with my game, and it took a little finagling of the numbers to get everything lined up. If you draw zoomed instead of zooming the drawing you will encounter the same problem gain at certain zoom leves.

Comment: How you pick adjacent tiles depends on which coordinate system you are using. The screenshot looks like the kind of error you get if you are using the adjacent-hex code for a different coordinate system than the one you are using in your project. Which coordinate system are you using, and can you show the code you use for picking adjacent tiles?

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens Zooming was causing the problem. How should i view the full map without zooming? Also by checking pixel placement what am I looking for? To make sure the there's no gaps between tiles? Thank you.

Comment: @amitp Honestly I'm not sure what co ordinate system Im using the bottom left of the screen is 0,0 as I am using libGDX and i had to edit my code a bit from the original adjacent finding code which made most of them work apart from the one you can see in the picture. Its strange. I'll add the code to the question

Comment: @amitp its staggered co ordinate system

Comment: @TheMagicShroom I'm guessing your code for adjacent tiles is for axial coordinates and not the staggered/offset system. If you test some more and find that the code works properly for even columns but not odd (or vice versa) then that would be the issue. I have [an article](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#neighbors) that shows pseudocode for finding the adjacent hexes.